# Add to max/min functions further information from related columns

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am using 10.1.39-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary and I have the following table:

```
| id  | product   | delivery_date       | issuer   | price_from | price_to | createdAt           | updatedAt           |
|-----|-----------|---------------------|----------|------------|----------|---------------------|---------------------|
| 452 | product 1 | 2019-09-17 22:00:00 | Issuer 1 | 247        | 247      | 2019-09-18 19:03:29 | 2019-09-18 19:03:29 |
| 454 | product 1 | 2019-09-14 22:00:00 | Issuer 2 | 245        | 245      | 2019-09-18 19:03:29 | 2019-09-18 19:03:29 |
| 455 | product 2 | 2019-09-12 22:00:00 | Issuer 3 | 150        | 150      | 2019-09-18 19:03:29 | 2019-09-18 19:03:29 |
| 456 | product 2 | 2019-09-12 22:00:00 | Issuer 4 | 187        | 165      | 2019-09-18 19:03:29 | 2019-09-18 19:03:29 |
| 457 | product 1 | 2019-09-11 22:00:00 | Issuer 5 | 247        | 247      | 2019-09-18 19:03:29 | 2019-09-18 19:03:29 |
```

I coded the following query:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR
FROM
    rating_date) AS 'Year',
    AVG(`price_from`) AS avg_1y_price_from,
    AVG(`price_to`) AS avg_1y_price_to,
    MAX(`price_from`) AS max_1y_price_from,
    MAX(`price_to`) AS max_1y_price_to,
    MIN(`price_from`) AS min_1y_price_from,
    MIN(`price_to`) AS min_1y_price_to
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    YEAR(delivery_date)
ORDER BY
    `Year`
DESC
```

However, I would like to show for each aggregate function the related issuer so that I get for `max_1y_price_from` the issuer that has the max value.

Any suggestions how to add the correct issuer?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Please fix the query in your question, it's invalid. I assume it's just a typo, but better fix it if you want to get accurate answers.

Comment: update your question add  a the expected  result  too ..

Comment: @RacilHilan I'm not sure that changing the table name counts as 'invalid'

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure what you're referring to by "changing the table name". I was referring to `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM rating_date)`. There is no column called `rating_date` in the table, so the query is invalid and will give an error. I assume the OP meant `delivery_date`, but can't be sure.

Comment: I added the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag. This type of question is asked frequently and there are many answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join`:

```
SELECT y.*, tmaxpfrom.issuer, tmaxpto.issuer, . . . 
FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM rating_date) AS Year,
             AVG(`price_from`) AS avg_1y_price_from,
             AVG(`price_to`) AS avg_1y_price_to,
             MAX(`price_from`) AS max_1y_price_from,
             MAX(`price_to`) AS max_1y_price_to,
             MIN(`price_from`) AS min_1y_price_from,
             MIN(`price_to`) AS min_1y_price_to
      FROM t
      GROUP BY YEAR(delivery_date)
     ) y LEFT JOIN
     t tmaxpfrom
     ON YEAR(tmaxpfrom.delivery_date) = y.year AND
        tmaxpfrom.price_to = max_1y_price_from LEFT JOIN
     t tmaxpto
     ON YEAR(tmaxpto.delivery_date) = y.year AND
        tmaxpto.price_to = max_1y_price_to LEFT JOIN
     . . . 
ORDER BY `Year` DESC
```

Just continue for all the columns where you want the list.

Note:  If there are duplicates, this will return multiple rows for the year.

Also, this would be easier in a more recent version of MariaDB, so you could use window functions.